# Is there a way to copy and paste values inside pickerInput widget in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, pickerinput

As a minimal example

```r
# Basic usage
library("shiny")
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "somevalue",
    label = "A label",
    choices = c("apple", "orange", "mango", "pear"),
    options = list(
    `actions-box` = TRUE,
    `live-search` = TRUE,
    `selected-text-format`= "count",
    `count-selected-text` = "{0} choosen (on a total of {1})"),
    multiple = T
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderPrint(input$somevalue)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there a way to copy and paste values into the search bar of `pickerInput` and return results that match?

for example, if I copy both lines below from a text file and I try to paste them inside the search bar, nothing is returned.

```
apple
mango
```

[image: gif]

Also, is it possible to print if the words did not match what's available from the list?

Edit 1: I have checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744568/copy-and-paste-text-in-selectizeinput-in-a-shiny-application) as suggested by Roman but this does not answer my question in this context. That question uses `selectizeInput` but I need to keep `pickerInput` for its functionalities.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy and paste text in selectizeInput in a Shiny application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744568/copy-and-paste-text-in-selectizeinput-in-a-shiny-application)

Comment: @Roman thanks but no. I actually have checked that question but it didn't really help as I needed the functionalities of `pickerInput` and that are `Select All` and `Deselect All`.